# Running a java.class file from Linux command line - Oracle JDK8 Installed - openJDK removed

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

So, I have removed openjdk from my new Ubuntu system and have installed Oracle JDK 8 and Eclipse from their respective websites. I can run a program from Eclipse, however I cannot run it from the command line. I am also not used to using Eclipse (I use NetBeans for my Java class in college.) I noticed that there is no build button in Eclipse. With all of that being said, here is my command line code:

```
wil@wil-Aspire-E5-521:~/eclipse-workspace/wiltest/src/wiltest$ ls
test.class  test.java
wil@wil-Aspire-E5-521:~/eclipse-workspace/wiltest/src/wiltest$ java wiltest.test.java
Error: Could not find or load main class wiltest.test.java
wil@wil-Aspire-E5-521:~/eclipse-workspace/wiltest/src/wiltest$ java wiltest.testError: Could not find or load main class wiltest.test
wil@wil-Aspire-E5-521:~/eclipse-workspace/wiltest/src/wiltest$ java test
Error: Could not find or load main class test
wil@wil-Aspire-E5-521:~/eclipse-workspace/wiltest/src/wiltest$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `-classpath .` command line option.

[You can learn more about classpaths here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

I believe the command `java -classpath . test` might work, but it really depends on a number of items that are better explained in the link above.

Comment: I read the article and now understand what classpath is and how to set it (like I did on my windows machine) but I am not sure how to enter the path in a Linux format.

Comment: @WilliamMcDowell For a Linux Path, just use any directory secification (absolute or relative).  It's just like the Windows Path, but you don't have a volume specification.  For example `./subdir` or `/home/myuser/myclasses` are relative and absolute path examples, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I actually answered part of my question myself. (For anybody wondering, the classpath is set to be in present working directory by default.) Anyways, I was running `java wiltest.test` from `src` and not `bin`. However, I ran from binary file and it worked. BUT I deleted the .class file thinking that I could change the source file, recompile using `javac`, and it would create another test.class in the binary folder. It did not. -sigh-

Comment: I tried to recreate my success in running the .class file from bin with no success, however I navigated back and over to src and ran java wiltest.test and it ran. Weird really. But there it is =)

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out.  Happy programming!